# dumping mysql database with cron in cpanel

Tags: cron, mysql, cpanel, cron-task

I have written a cron job for dumping my mysql database but it's not working.

Here it is.

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump -h localhost --user=user --password=mypass --databases dbname | gzip &gt; /home/username/site_dir_name/uploads/backup.sql.gz
```

I am using cpanel.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
mysqldump -u{user name without space} -p{password without space} Database_name | gzip -9 > /home/backup_$(date +"\%Y.\%m.\%d.\%S.\%N").sql.gz 2> /home/db.log
```

add this line into cron job.